# Selenium multiple test run fails

Tags: selenium, testng

I am having one suit say Suite1

in Suite1  I am calling two class methods Test1 and Test2 respectively with test annotation @Test and having main method with @Beforesuite and @AfterSuite annotation - when I run the suite using Test NG - it runs only the second method and first method always fails and below it the trace of failed result.

I am just curious why always last test pass and this happens when I use selenium keyword but I use standard java keyword like system.out.println(); it pass the test

Comment: Can you please provide your testng xml file and class?

Comment: Also please provide the trace message.